# FQl and Graph API: is tehre a way to get "hidden posts" in a page's wall (feed/stream)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In FQL and Graph APi, i am no longer able to get all posts in a page's feed (stream FQL table),
i don't see hidden posts, even if i put "... WHERE (is_hidden = 0 OR is_hidden = 1)"

Comment: Can you post an example page where this is happening?

Comment: In all pages that i have, 
i have a wall tab and under it a "hidden posts" tab.

Sometimes, some posts goes to "hidden posts" and not in my wall.

And when i want to have all "streams" in FQL or graph API, i can't have hidden posts.

Do you know how have them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/ there is no documentation on is_hidden flag on the **columns** list.

But there is only one example (the first one on that page) that uses this flag.

In https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_filter/ there is a flag called
is_visible

I don't know... but if I was in charge of documentation or the API, I would put an **is_hidden** flag on stream/feed

But there must be some methods we could get the hidden filtering option from the API. but since the facebook documentation is so awesome, I just can not find it...

So please direct us to the right direction facebook people ;)

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use in the where clause (is_hidden OR is_published)

For instance SELECT message, is_hidden FROM stream Where source_id = [page_id] and (is_hidden or is_published)