# Is there a way using any of Facebook's APIs to get the posts made to a Page that have automatically been hidden

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FQl and Graph API: is tehre a way to get "hidden posts" in a page's wall (feed/stream)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041039/fql-and-graph-api-is-tehre-a-way-to-get-hidden-posts-in-a-pages-wall-feed-st)

When people post to my Facebook page's wall they are sometimes (always?) automatically hidden and I have to manually go to the wall_admin page and unhide them.

www.facebook.com/pages/[PAGE_NAME]/[PAGE_ID]?sk=wall_admin

My question is if there is a way using any of Facebook's APIs to retrieve these posts that have automatically been hidden.

I have tries using the Graph and FQL but the both only display posts that are not hidden.

graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]/feed

api.facebook.com/method/fql.queryquery=SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=[PAGE_ID]

If I add is_hidden=1 to the FQL request no posts are returned.

api.facebook.com/method/fql.queryquery=SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=[PAGE_ID] AND is_hidden=1

I of course use acccess_tokens for all requests. I have tried with both the access_token I get for a user if I accept the apps permissions and as the access_token you get for the page with:

graph.facebook.com/me/accounts

If there is no way to get these posts does anybody know of a way to disable so that Facebook does not automatically hide posts from a Page's wall?

(I have removed http:// and https:// from all URLs because StackOverflow prevents me from posting more then 2 links because I am a new user)