# Facebook - Is it possible to get hidden posts and comments in grey via Graph API or FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have some comments in grey in my Facebook pages's wall and some comments in "Hidden posts" Page tab, not in the wall.

I know that Facebook anti-spam filter has put theses comments but i want to know if it's possible to get them via Graph API or FQL?

Thanks !

Comment: See this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041039/fql-and-graph-api-is-tehre-a-way-to-get-hidden-posts-in-a-pages-wall-feed-s