# making post hidden with graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, curl

i have post created calling graph api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed/?access_token=<token>
```

it returns somthing like:
{"id":"<UID>_<POST_ID>"}

now i want to hide this post by api call

```
curl -F "is_hidden=true" "https://graph.facebook.com/<POST_ID>?access_token=<token>
```

but i am geting this response:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter reorder_pids is required", "type": "OAuthException", "code":100}}
```

is here somebody who using api for this? (hiding post)
if yes, is it working for you? ;)

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to hide the post from facebook page.

```
curl -F "timeline_visibility=hidden" "https://graph.facebook.com/<POST_ID>/?access_token=<page_token>
```

...and it return true.

Answer (score 1):

It only works when the post is published by a non-admin user.

Answer (score 0):

Is it actually possible to update a post's privacy after the fact like that?
I'm not sure.

You can set the privacy field on the initial create though.

```
 privacy={'value':'SELF'}
```

See

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/
and
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/privacy-parameter/

Comment: i want to set is_hidden parameter, not privacy

Comment: My research around their API docs is coming up short.But is this any help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9003362/1238737

Comment: Also, see here. Looks like its supported for Page Posts only...https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#attributes   "You can hide a Page post that is published by a non-admin user by issuing an HTTP POST to /POST_ID with the following parameter:"